# Как узнать, что выбрал юзер в "Ask to bay" алерте?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchases

Если у пользователя встроенные покупки проверяет и одобряет родитель, то перед покупкой он увидит алерт. Как узнать какую из кнопок он нажал? У меня перед началом покупок появляется activityIndecator и мне нужно его спрятать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

У нативного StoreKit есть делегат SKPaymentTransactionObserver в котором есть метод:
`func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])`
Он отрабатывает, когда массив транзакций изменился (добавление или изменение состояния).

```
extension SubscriptionsService: SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case .purchased, .failed, .restored, .deferred, .purchasing:
                // реализация кейсов
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык